# Transferring chars from java to c++: Issue with endianness

Tags: java, c++, sockets, endianness, utf-16

I've run into mind twisting bafflement after putting my hands into an old legacy project. The project consists of a Java application and a c++ application, which communicate with sockets. Both applications are designed to work on cross platform environments, so I'd be happy to keep the code as universal as possible.

I ended up rewriting parts of the communication logic, since the previous implementation had some issues with foreign characters. Now I ran into a problem with endianness, which I hope someone could spell out for me.

The Java software writes messages to socket with OutputStreamWriter, using UTF-16LE encoding, as follows.

```
OutputStream out = _socket.getOutputStream();
outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(out), "UTF-16LE");

// ... create msg

outputWriter.write(msg, 0, msg.length());
outputWriter.flush();
```

The c++ program receives the message character by character as follows:

```
char buf[1];
std::queue<char> q;
std::u16string recUtf16Msg;

do {
    int iResult = recv(socket, buf, 1, 0);

    if (iResult <= 0)
        break; // Error or EOS

    for (int i = 0; i < iResult; i++) {
        q.push(buf[i]);
    }

    while (q.size() >= 2) {
        char firstByte = q.front();
        q.pop();
        char secondByte = q.front();
        q.pop();
        char16_t utf16char = (firstByte << (sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT)) ^
                             (0x00ff & secondByte);

        // Change endianness, if necessary
        utf16char = ntohs(utf16char);

        recUtf16Msg.push_back(utf16char);
    }

    // ... end of message check removed for clarity
} while (true);
```

Now the issue which I'm really facing is that the code above actually works, but I'm not really sure why. The c++ side is written to receive messages which use network byte order (big endian) but it seems that java is sending the data using little endian encoding.

On c++ side we even use ntons-function to change endianness to the one desired by host machine. According to specification I understand that hton is supposed to do swap endianness if host platform uses little endian byte order. However ntonhs actually swaps the endianness of the received small endian characters, which ends up as big endian and the software works flawlessly.

Maybe someone can point out what exactly is happening? Do I accidentally switch bytes already to when creating utf16char? Why htons makes everything work, while it seems to act exactly opposite to the documentation? To compile I'm using Clang with libc++.

I left out parts of the code for clarity, but you should get the general idea. Also, I'm aware that using queue and dynamic array may not be the most effective way of handling data, but it's clean and performs well enough for this purpose.

Comment: Could it be that your `buf` only consists of one `char`, and you only read one `char` from the socket into it, while utf16 uses two `char`s?

Comment: I've actually tested this with different buffer sizes (1, 2 and 5). Each one produces the same result. Order of received bytes in buffer is not affected by the size of buffer

Comment: No, the order of bytes isn’t affected, but when sending `1` as the third argument to recv, you will always only read 1 byte, so you actually never push the `secondByte` into `q`. I think you have undefined behaviour. `iResult` will be the number of bytes successfully read, so you neither check for errors. I just wanted to point out that. I can’t help you with the endianness — sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) However, I did change the third argument accordingly when testing different buffer sizes. Also, my actual implementation includes error handling (loop is broken if recv returns zero or negative), but I left it out from the code above for clarity.